# Select mulitple objects (buttons) using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have three buttons in my Excel spreadsheet called `Button_01`, `Button_02` and `Button_03`. 
 Now, I want to select all of them and tried to go with the following VBA:

```
Sub Select_Objects()
Sheet1.Buttons("Button_01").Select
Sheet1.Buttons("Button_02").Select
Sheet1.Buttons("Button_03").Select
End Sub
```

This VBA only selects each of the buttons one after another so in the end only `Button_03` is selected.

What do I need to change in this code so all three buttons remain selected. 
 The same if I would select them manually with `Ctrl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sheet1.Shapes.Range(Array("Button_01", "Button_02", "Button_03")).Select
```

Hope it helps